# Server is responding with unwanted response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch-api

From the frontend, I am making a post request with fetch API in React js. I give URL to the server. Server receives the URL. In the function, the URL is used for an API (clarifai API) call. API (clarifai API) responses with my wanted response but when I send that response from server to the frontend side the response become unwanted. This is my frontend code :

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/imageurl", {
  method: "post",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    url: this.state.input,
  }),
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

The `console.log(response)` above in the code gives the unwanted response as below.

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8000/imageurl", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:8000/imageurl"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: "OK"
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

And this is my server side code for that particular request:

```
const faceApp = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: "#####################",
});
app.post("/imageurl", (req, res) => {
  faceApp.models
    .predict(Clarifai.DEMOGRAPHICS_MODEL, req.body.url)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('data : ', response);
      res.json(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("unable to work with API"));
});
```

While the `console.log('data : ', response);` above in the server side code gives the actual wanted response that is:

```json
data :  {
  status: {
    code: 10000,
    description: 'Ok',
    req_id: '658c1630d58e47f19cd5372334c1b20a'
  },
  outputs: [
    {
      id: '7cd142ff9cd44b6e8dfa46801451f5a4',
      status: [Object],
      created_at: '2020-06-26T05:07:16.225523417Z',
      model: [Object],
      input: [Object],
      data: [Object]
    }
  ],
  rawData: {
    status: {
      code: 10000,
      description: 'Ok',
      req_id: '658c1630d58e47f19cd5372334c1b20a'
    },
    outputs: [ [Object] ]
  }
}
```

When I send that Clarifai response from server side to the frontend side the response become unwanted.

Comment: It’s a `Response` object. If you want the data you’ll need to read it from it. For example using `json()` method in the object. Or you can just look at the `body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please edit your code to include the below, right after fetch in the chain:

`.then(r => r.json())`

Comment: Sorry missed the equals sign in the code example. Please have a look and see if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the response it seems that its related with Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS).
Try adding cors headers in the response you are sending.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Make sure you're aware about CORS before implementing this.

Comment: If this was the case of CORS then browser will throw an error of it.